# Xarray indexing / slicing to account for seasons

Tags: indexing, python-xarray, object-slicing

I am using xarray to proccess a pretty long data set. It has been very much fun and I was able to find everything I needed in the [online documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/index.html). However now I try to plot data for *summer* and *winter*, and it won't work. While I found a lot of documentation on calculating means, I have not found anything on "pure" data. So my code is:

In *winter*:

```
da.loc[(dataD['time.month']>10 & dataD['time.month']<3)]
```

And in *summer*:

```
da.loc[(dataD['time.month']>4 & dataD['time.month']<9)]
```

Which should give me all the data for November to February and May to August. However I always run into the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I also tried slicing, like

```
dataH.sel(time=slice('1995-06-01', '2005-06-10'))
```

but I couldn't find a way to skip either the winter or summer months in between.

Btw:**I want to avoid looping through the data (90k elements!).** I really like the xarray (dask?!?) way to deal with data, so I'd love to keep the code clean and elegant :)

I would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close: you just need an extra set of parentheses when using element-wise comparison and binary operations:

```
da.loc[(dataD['time.month']>10) | (dataD['time.month']<3)]  # winter
da.loc[(dataD['time.month']>4) & (dataD['time.month']<9)]  # summer
```

(Binary operators like `&` bind more tightly than comparisons like `>` in Python.)

Another option that can be slightly more readable is to use the `isin()` method (requires xarray v0.10.3 or newer):

```
ds.loc[dataD['time.month'].isin([1, 2, 11, 12])]  # winter
ds.loc[dataD['time.month'].isin([5, 6, 7, 8])]  # summer
```

Comment: Sorry, to ask once more. *Summer* will work fine now, but *winter* (the one you displayed) will be empty. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use `|` instead of `&` for winter. I updated my answer and also added an alternative using `isin()`.

Comment: Thanks @shoyer That's so awesome!